# Python progress bar from callback function

Tags: python, python-3.x

From what I've seen progress bars mostly work by wrapping an iterable or something the like.
I'm trying to get a progress bar from a callback function from another module.

The module is doing calculating on data and you can define a callback that uses three arguments:
(file being worked on, current piece, total pieces)

Just for fun I did this:

```
def callback(filename, pc, num_pieces):
    print(f'{filename} - {pc} - {num_pieces}')
```

As expected, you get thousands of prints with increasing piece number:
The file name also changes during the progress, but it's not important for my purposes.

How would you define and use the callback to create a progress bar for a CLI application?

Comment: can you just call `tqdm.update` after each invocation of the callback?

Answer (score 2):

I have done something similar with TQDM.

If you have a classical callback, change it into update_to function, it would look somewhat like mine:

```
class DownloadProgressBar(tqdm):
    def update_to(self, current, total):
        self.total = total
        self.update(current - self.n)
```

And register the callback regularly with your DownloadProgressBar.

```
with DownloadProgressBar(unit='B', unit_scale=True) as t:
            client.download_media(media, filepath , progress_callback=t.update_to)
```

For more information look up at their [Official docs.](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#hooks-and-callbacks)

( Keep in mind my example is showing a callback on a single file )